# Why do we need prototype in function?

Tags: c, function, function-prototypes

I'm studying C and my book is explaining how to "prototype a function" so we can use it before we define it.

The point is that I can't imagine a situation in which is needed to use a function before have defined it, why can't we just define it at the beginning?

Can you please provide an example in which is strictly necessary to prototype a function (if it exists)?

Comment: Imagine you have `is_even(int n)` and `is_odd(int n)` defined in terms of each other. How would you write that?

Comment: Note that you *can* use a function without a prototype, it is enough to *declare* a function (even without a prototype). (But that is deprecated.)

Comment: You've just started learning, but you'll soon find out that C programs aren't usually written in a single file. That makes it impractical to "always define them before using them".

Comment: Because the function definition might not be local, or already visible. If the function is in a library, the compiler does not have access to its definition, so the prototype is needed for the compiler to know how to interface.

Comment: By the way, that's not what "prototype" means in C.

Comment: Consider two local functions that call each other in a flip-flop fashion. They can't *both* know each other's interface, unless at least one of them has a function prototype, because c is a one-pass compiler.

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks a lot!! I had not thought of this possibility!

Comment: One reason: the standard C library headers declare the functions in the library, but they don't implement them, and neither do you.  So, you need the declarations of the functions to ensure you use them accurately.

Comment: A definition does double-duty as a prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One use-case is when you want to **take a function pointer to a function defined in another source file**.  (Or hand-written in asm).  Taking a function-pointer always requires the function to be declared ahead of time, either by a definition or a prototype.

C89 (and earlier) allows implicit declaration of functions (use them even if there's no definition or prototype earlier in the compilation unit (this .c + anything you `#include`).

So you *can* compile this in a file by itself, in C89 (or [with a warning from most compilers in C99 / C11 mode](https://godbolt.org/z/5ed31PaWh))

```
int foo() {
    return bar( 123 );   /* implicit declaration of  int bar()  */
}
```

But you *can't* use `&bar` as a function pointer

```
/* int bar(int);      necessary if you haven't defined  int bar(int x) { ... } */
void *take_fptr() {
     return &bar;    // error: 'bar' undeclared   from GCC
}
```

---

You can also construct cases where a declaration is needed to get args passed correctly, e.g. if you want your function to take a `float` arg, you *need* it to be declared, either by a definition or prototype.  The "Default Argument Promotions" in the ISO C standard will promote `float` to `double` when passing an arg to an unprototyped function, or to the `...` part of a variadic function like printf.

(That's why `%f` prints a double, not a float, and why `%lf` is also a double if it's supported at all.  Also why functions like `putchar(int)` take their char arg as an int: default promotions of narrow integer types up to `int`.  Some parts of the C standard library date back to very early C, before the language supported prototypes!)

Or for example, if your function is expecting a `long long`, but the caller writes `bar( 123 )`, the caller will only infer `int`, which may be passed differently from a `long long`.  But you can fix that by writing `bar( 123LL )`, or `bar( (long long)123 )`

Or if the return type isn't `int` (or `void`), then you also need the compiler to know about the function via a declaration.  Implicitly-declared functions are assumed to return `int`.  Depending on the calling convention and architecture, you might get away with that for a `short` return type, or on some machines even for a `char*`, e.g. on 32-bit machines where `intptr_t` is `int`.  (Early C relied on that.)

But in general, e.g. on machines with 64-bit pointers, implicit-int return isn't going to work.  Nor will it work for a `double` return value, or a `struct`.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add(int, int);

int main() {
    add(5, 3);
    return 0;
}

void add(int a, int b) {
    printf("%d", a+b);
}
```

Here, when you call `add(5, 3)` from `main()`, the compiler knows what `add()` is - the parameters it takes and the return type, thanks to the statement `void add(int, int)` in line 3.  If this statement is commented out, then the compiler won't know what `add()` is and would give you an error.  Thus, line 3 tells the compiler that you have defined the function `add()` later, which makes it perfectly eligible to be used in `main()`.  Alternately, if you write the `add()` function *before* `main()`, then the compiler knows what `add()` is when you call it; so a function prototype is not required in this case.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: This is exactly the case where it's really simple to omit the prototype and just put the `add` function before `main`. :)

Comment: @Groo, I have edited the answer to include your comments as well.  Thank you.

Comment: in Pascal you don't have a prototype and must always declare the function before main. I prefer this way and never use prototypes in a single-file program. Prototypes should only be in header files in complex projects

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc,  There is a lot that can be 'gotten away with' in a single file, very simple, program.  However, real programs (not simple homework programs that are being used to teach a concept) cannot be written the way you are envisioning.  AND for `gcc`, the parameter: `Wmissing-prototypes` will cause the compiler to complain anytime any prototype is missing including this: `int main()`.  the compiler will want `int main( void )`,  One more thing,  This is `C`, not `Pascal`

Comment: @user3629249 where did I say that this is not C? I just say that I prefer not use prototypes in very simple single-file programs, because it's useless and in that case there's not even a header file. In big projects of course headers must be used, and still there should be no prototype in source file

Comment: in your case you can omit prototype completely. It would compile on most of the compilers since your return type is `int`.

Answer (score -1):

The definition of the function may not be known at that time. Imagine a program that calls `malloc` to allocate memory. At compile time, nobody has any idea what allocator the program will be using at run time. So how can you define the function then?

Comment: I think you are up to something here, but pls explain it more!!!!